# Bottom navigation items quit the applicaiton when pressing on back button of the phone

Tags: android, debugging, bottomnavigationview

I've implemented a bottom navigation in my application and it's working fine, but today I've tried to press the back button of the phone when I'm inside some activity, while doing so, I've noticed that it pretty much takes me out of the app , is there a way to solve this? for example instead of it taking me to the outside of app i want it to take me to home activity, is there some method i'm supposed to be using to handle these changes? if so please let me know, my code for the bottom navigation in the(for example exercice acitvity since i use the bottom navigation in 3 different activities)is :

```
public class Exercice extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference ref;
    ArrayList<Deal> list;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercice);
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("medicines");
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchview);
       /* RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
*/
        //initialize  and assign variables
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        //set home selected
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.exercice);
        //preform itemsselectedlistener
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.exercice:
                        finish();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.profile:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , MainActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        finish();

                        return true;
                    case R.id.home:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , Home.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        finish();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(ref != null){
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                    return super.clone();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        list = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                            list.add(ds.getValue(Deal.class));
                        }
                        AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(list);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Exercice.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        if (searchView != null){
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    search(newText);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private void search(String str) {
        if (!str.equals("")){
            ArrayList<Deal> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Deal object : list){
                if(object.getDisease().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())){
                    myList.add(object);
                }
            }
            AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(myList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you removed the `HomeActivity` from the back stack .. How do you launch the `Exercise` activity? How the activity navigation looks like?

Comment: @Zain i left the id of exercise empty because i'm already inside it, i've done the same for when I'm inside home activity,i keep the r.id empty whenever i'm in the activity that i need to be in , i can access this from both profile acitvty and home, since i've set an intent just like i've set it here to go to home and profile

Comment: Do you have a separate bottom navigation inside each activity then?